# How list slicing works for finding sum of element by using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

```
def s(arr):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr[0]

    return arr[0] + s(arr[1:])
```

Above code is to find the sum of a list using recursion.
So when I call the function again by giving a slicing list isn't the length of the list always gonna be same after every recursion call?
Then how is my base condition is satisfying?

Comment: No, the slize is obviously shorter than the original.

Comment: `arr[1:]` would create a new list with only the elements from index `1` till the end of the list. So, on every iteration one element will be reduced.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `s` calls recursively itself on a shrinked version of the `arr` parameter: this is done due to `s(arr[1:])` statement.

1. First call: `arr` points to `[1,2,3]`
2. Second call: `arr` points to `[2,3]`
3. Third call: `arr` points to `[3]`

At this point, since `len([3]) == 1` the return value is `3` and so on recursively, *popping* one activation record at time from the stack (LIFO).

A demo here: [demo](https://pythontutor.com/render.html#code=def%20s%28arr%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20len%28arr%29%20%3D%3D%201%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20arr%5B0%5D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20arr%5B0%5D%20%2B%20s%28arr%5B1%3A%5D%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0Aprint%28s%28%5B1,2,3%5D%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Answer (score 0):

When you slice a list, it creates a new list, typically with a smaller number of elements.

You can verify it easily by using `print` to examine the lists:

```py
def print_indexed_list(l):
    print(dict(enumerate(l)))

arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

print_indexed_list(arr)
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'}

print_indexed_list(arr[1:])
{0: 'b', 1: 'c', 2: 'd', 3: 'e'}

print_indexed_list(arr[:4])
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd'}

print_indexed_list(arr[1:3])
{0: 'b', 1: 'c'}

print_indexed_list(arr[::2])
{0: 'a', 1: 'c', 2: 'e'}
```